# Cannot run simple HelloWorld class

Tags: java, runtime-error

I'm trying to compile simple Java `HelloWorld` source on Windows. I compile it the following way:

```
javac HelloWorld.java
```

But then when I run it like this

```
java HelloWorld.class
```

I get an error

```
Could not find or load main class HelloWorld.class
```

But the file is there, any hints?

Comment: Do `java HelloWorld`. For more info, read this : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/cupojava/win32.html#win32-2c

Comment: start here with a tutorial for java program http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/index.html

Comment: @ZouZou is right. Also, make sure your PATH variable is set correctly for you to run the java / javac commands from anylocation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is rather a basic step towards Java development and it's important!
say you have a Java file named:  `Main.java` , open it by your favorite editor:

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        System.out.println("Rugal");
    }
}
```

Now just exit your editor and use `javac` to compile:

`javac Main.java`

which will generate a `Main.class` file.
Then you can use `java` to launch a `JVM` to execute this `main` method in class `Main`.

`java Main`

notice that as your class name is `Main` thus you need to execute the `Main` class.
here you need not to include `.class` suffix after the class name.

If you have package name in this class, just use:
`java your.package.name.Main`  to execute.

Yes, is that easy? start your journey in Java!

Answer (score 3):

Run it like this:

```
java HelloWorld
```

Do not put `.class` suffix after the class name.

Answer (score 3):

```
java -cp . HelloWorld
```

The `.` is needed in order to tell Java to include the current directory in the classpath.
`HelloWorld` is the name of the class to run (must not add the `.class` suffix).

Comment: If the `CLASSPATH` variable is set and doesn't contain the current directory then you may need this, otherwise the [current directory is searched by default](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html#classpath).

Answer (score 1):

`javac HelloWorld.java` is ok But then

use

```
java HelloWorld
```

`

Answer (score 1):

To run `java` program

```
java HelloWorld
```

(w/o .class extension)

**[NOTE]**

Tutorials for beginners http://www.javabeginner.com/

Answer (score 1):

Compiling your java file using `javac HelloWorld.java` is fine but when your try run it do like this. `java HelloWorld`. 
**

**NOTE** : Use only class name while running your compiled code.